# Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindparam()

Tags: php, pdo

```
$txtEmail = $_POST['txtEmail'];
$txtPassword = $_POST['txtPassword'];

echo $txtEmail."<br>";
echo $txtPassword."<br>";

$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM adm_login_info WHERE cEmail=$txtEmail AND cPassword=$txtPassword AND cLoginStat=1 AND cLock=0 ");
$STHA->bindparam(":txtEmail",$txtEmail);
$STHA->bindparam(":txtPassword",$txtPassword);
$STHA->execute();
```

Please I need your help, I'm trying to solve this. Please Check on my codes if there is something I missed out.

Comment: Where are you creating your connection kindly share or also where you are initializing PDO something like $DBH = new PDO('dblib:host=' . $serverUrl . ';dbname=' . $serverDb, $serverUser, $serverPass);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindParam` is a method of a PDO statement, but you are  trying to use it with the undefined variable `$STHA`.

preparing a SQL query with your database handler (`$DBH->prepare(...)` in your case) returns a PDO statement. you have to use this to bind parameters and execute your query:

```
$STHA = $DBH->prepare(...); // prepare returns a "statement"
$STHA->bindParam(...); // use the statement to bind your parameters
// ...
$STHA->execute()
```

also notice that `bindParam` is written with a capital P.

**update:** you are also not using your named parameters in your SQL query, you are just using your PHP variables. use the named parameters instead:

```
$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM adm_login_info 
WHERE cEmail = :txtEmail 
AND cPassword = :txtPassword AND cLoginStat=1 AND cLock=0 ");
```

Comment: what should I do to make it right? how can I use $STHA to be a defined variable? tnx

Comment: You could spend some words about security issues of op code

Comment: @low_rents

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@sample.com AND cPassword=123 AND cLoginStat=1 AND cLock=0' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_final_exam\login.php:18 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\web_final_exam\login.php(18): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_final_exam\login.php on line 18

Comment: i tried what you said but it seems i have access violation : 1064

Comment: @fabio that's not part of OP's question.

Comment: @SchwarzSpiel no, not really - you just have more errors in your code. you need to use the names parameters in your SQL - not the PHP variables. otherwise using and binding parameters doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @SchwarzSpiel see my updated answer - it shows you how to use your named parameters correctly.

Comment: @Fabio it's not about security issues at all - it's about OP not knowing how to use PDO. since he can't use his code as it is cause it doesn't work, there are no security issues at all.

Comment: @low_rents! You're awesome I already did it! Thanks for the big help!

Comment: There were when he throw variables directly in query

Comment: @SchwarzSpiel no problem, using PDO is my everyday's life. please consider marking my answer as accepted if it did help you solve your question.

Comment: @low_rents yes I will thank you, now I can move forward with my life (kidding)